# Connect MSSQL DB as different Windows user in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, windows-authentication

I need to establish connection to MSSQL database from java using Windows Authentication as a different user

I getting SQL login failiure because windows authentication is using server username and password. I would like to change those.

```
this.connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER;DatabaseName=DATABASE;integratedSecurity=true";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url);
            this.statement = conn.createStatement();
```

I expect to log into remote database as a different windows user.

Many thanks in Advance

Comment: What about `this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username, password);`? Sure, you have to provide them in the variables `username` and `password`.

Comment: Hello tried and login fails. Server demands windows authentication. What you mention is SQL authentication. But thanks anyway

Comment: can u try with your windows credentials ?

Comment: Hello, When I keep server credentials (Im using IIB to connect)  it fails as server domain user has no acces to remoteDB (We have domain user that has access everywhere, tested from MSSQL Managemet Studio). I already asked to grant server user acces to database but until ithis is done, id like to find out how acchieve this. Thanks